# Stripe: how to get the count of payment methods attached to the customer object? (Node SDK)

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Is there a way to get only the count (Integer) of attached payment methods, not the list of actual payment method objects?

We have API to get the list of payment method objects. But we don't need it for our server logic in a particular case. Counter would suffice.

The API for the list of payment methods is here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list

Answer (score 0):

Stripe does not currently have an API method that returns just the count of Customer payment methods.  You would need to retrieve a list of the Payment Methods using the approach you already specified and use the `.length` property of the `data` array returned like so:

```js
const paymentMethods = await stripe.customers.listPaymentMethods(
  'cus_LL88RV9IZ7qs6x',
  {type: 'card'}
);
return paymentMethods.data.length
```

Comment: Well, it's a quite unfortunate that there is no request to just get the counter. It would be really useful considering their limitation of 100 payment methods per customer.